# Seurat FindClusters() seems to freeze after one iteration

Tags: r, multiprocessing, hpc, seurat

I am trying to run FindClusters() on a dataset of about 20G, 300K cells using the following command on a RedHat Linux HPC:

`df <- FindClusters(df, resolution=seq(0.01,1,by=0.1), verbose = TRUE,algorithm=1)`

When running, I get the following output in my file, however, the code then seems to freeze after the following input.

```
0%   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
[----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
****************************************************

Modularity Optimizer version 1.3.0 by Ludo Waltman and Nees Jan van Eck

Number of nodes: 311049
Number of edges: 5724294

Running Louvain algorithm...
Maximum modularity in 10 random starts: 0.9925
Number of communities: 2834
Elapsed time: 146 seconds
```

After this message, the program continues to run but doesn't seem to progress forward. Only after about 8 hours, does the next output for the next resolution value print. The program does work on a smaller dataset much faster (2G and about 4 min), and completes without any error, however, I don't believe that a 20G dataset should take this long.

These are the RedHat HPC system settings, and I am submitting my job via the following qsub command: `qsub multiCore.sh`

```
NAME="Springdale Linux"
VERSION="7.9 (Verona)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="7.9"
```

```
cat multiCore.sh
#!/bin/bash
#$ -N MULTICORE
#$ -cwd -S /bin/bash
#$ -l mem=50G,time=6::
#$ -pe orte 4
#$ -o output.log
#$ -e error.log


# Run the MPI job with mpirun
mpirun $HOME/bin/Rscript integrate2.R // integrate2.R is the file where FindClusters() is called
```

So far, I have tried looking through the Seurat documentation for parallel processing with future and running one resolution value at a time, but the issue persists.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.